# How to install a dummy printer by command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, printer, inf

i need to install a fake/dummy printer on windows using a command or a batch file.

I was able to install a dummy printer using the wizard and selecting a NUL port.
The problem is that i need to add the dummy printer automatically, so the wizard is not an option.

In my search for a solution i found that it is possible to execute the **[rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx)** command with the **/il** parameter to install a printer using a **.inf** file.

The problem is creating the .inf file. I read some documentation and tutorials but i still have no idea what this file must contain. Any ideas with this?

Also I'm not sure if the **rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry** command with a custom .inf file is the right answer, so i'm listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "NUL Printer" /f "%systemroot%\inf\ntprint.inf" /r "nul:" /m "HP DesignJet 755CM/PS" /z
```

## Update 1:

Postscript printer Name XP/2003:

```
findstr /S ModelName %windir%\*.ppd
findstr /S ModelName %windir%\system32\spool\drivers\*.ppd
findstr /S ModelName %windir%\SysWOW64\*.ppd
```

Unpack driver.cab! Postscript printer name XP/2003:

```
findstr /S ModelName "%windir%\Driver Cache\amd64\driver\*.ppd" | more
@for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=:" %a in ('findstr /S ModelName "%windir%\Driver Cache\amd64\driver\*.ppd"') do @echo %d >>c:\prname.txt
```

inf:

```
findstr /S Class\=Printer %windir%\system32\DRVSTORE\*.inf
findstr /S Class\=Printer %windir%\inf\*.inf
```

Search printer name at xml and ini-files too.

Set port `FILE:` and print *.ps file.
Convert .ps -> .pdf or view print page in [`PS Viewer`](http://psviewer.org/).

I install HP Designjet Z6200ps 60in PS3 printer driver to print large page to pdf (ps->pdf).

Max MS Office page size - 558,7x558,7 mm.

## [Printer INF Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560902(v=vs.85).aspx)

See too [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) offline (ISO CD to Visual Studio), DDK, [WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513), [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/).

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question - **The problem is creating the .inf file**

Comment: This actually worked, the only thing i had to change was the printer driver because i'm using windows 8 and kept getting error 0x00000705. `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "NUL Printer" /f "%systemroot%\inf\ntprint.inf" /r "nul:" /m "Microsoft PS Class Driver" /z`. Now i'm wondering if there is a printer driver that already comes in windows xp/7/8

Comment: @fsobral Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting the accepted solution working on multiple versions of Windows, due to the drivers present.

The "Generic / Text Only" driver is present in all my target OS's (Win7 Embedded and Win8.1), so this modification worked for me:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Null Printer" /f "%systemroot%\inf\ntprint.inf" /r "nul:" /m "Generic / Text Only" /z
```

Use `$ENV:systemroot` instead of `%systemroot%` if calling from PowerShell.